# Model Relationship with Pivot Table in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a table with the following columns:

plan_submission_plan_id

h_r_admin_id

This is a pivot table and there is no primary key.

I have the following in my controller:

```
    public function index()
{
    //Get ID of currently logged in HR Admin
    $id = Auth::guard('h_r_admin')->id();
    //Get HR Admin (for view composer)
    $admin = HRAdmin::find($id);
    //Get plan ID that is attached for HR Admin

    //Get all Plan Submissions this HR Admin is mapped to
    $plans = PSPlanToHRAdminMapping::where('h_r_admin_id', $id)->get();

    return view('hr-admin.planbuilder-submission-list', compact('plans', 'admin'));
}
```

I have the following in my view:

```
       @foreach($plans as $plan)
            <tr>
                <td> {{$plan->plan_submission_plan_id}}</td>
```

I need to be able to use the 'plan_submission_plan_id' to look up and output fields from my PlanSubmissions table.  Normally, if there were a primary key, I would create a model relationship on the model and retrieve the fields with something like $plan->plansubmission->advisor.  However, I don't think I can do that since there is no primary key.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the   `belongsToMany(`)  and `withPivot()` exemple

```
  public function sale_invoices()
      {
          return $this->belongsToMany(Invoice::class,'product_invoice_items', 'invoice_id', 'product_id')->withPivot(['quantity','total']);
      }
```